# Difference between `set end of` and `set the end of` (Applescript)

Tags: applescript

Is there a difference between the two following commands (with `the` in there or not)?

```
set {the_list, blah} to {{},"Test"}
set end of the_list to blah
```

---

```
set {the_list, blah} to {{},"Test"}
set the end of the_list to blah
```

This is usually working with lots of `blah` going into `the_list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference. "the" is just a word to improve readability but it does nothing when applescript performs the code.

Comment: Cool thanks. I kinda figured as much but just to be sure